# How to stop System Update from Canvas A1?

Tags: android-one

Android version of my Canvas A1 (AQ4501) is 4.4.4. And its rooted.

Now I am getting System Update for Android 6.0.

How to stop System Update for my rooted Canvas A1? and

If I update it to Android 6.0, will it affect root access?

Regards

Ugn10

Answer (score 1):

> How to stop System Update for my rooted Canvas A1?

**PROCEDURE to disable the Google Official OTA updates completely:**

*. You need to be rooted for this.

1. Install this app: [**Disable Services**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=cn.wq.disableservice&hl=en) and open it.
2. Select the '***System***' tab.
3. Select the "*Google Services Framework*" app and uncheck (**disable**) the following service: ***SystemUpdateService***
4. Again, select the "*Google Play Services*" app and uncheck this service: ***SystemUpdateService***

Tested and working on Android One devices & Google Nexus.

That's it! You'll never get the update notification and neither will you be able to check it manually.

If you feel you want the updates again, you can re-enable these services again to receive updates.

(Source: **[[TIP] How to disable the Google OTA updates completely](http://forum.xda-developers.com/crossdevice-dev/android-one-general/tip-how-to-disable-ota-updates-t3060697)**)

> If I update it to Android 6.0, will it affect root access?

Yes, definitely it will affect the root access.
BTW, you won't even be able to install the OTA zip (since you have rooted the stock KitKat, by which system partition is modified).

Comment: Hi..thank you for replying and giving resolution for my concern but dear..as I mentioned that my device is rooted and I given root access to Disable Services app. System Update Service was already unchecked. However I see the System Update. Currently I uncheck Google Play Service notification but I don't think, issue is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

why dont you want to update? i would highly recomend updating as it will not affect root *to my knowledge*. if it does, just root it again? you can use kingo root: https://www.kingoapp.com/ it works *most* of the times.

Comment: Hi..in my family, there are two Canvas A1 (AQ4501). One is rooted with 4.4.4 and another is non-rooted with updated 6.0.1. Because of low internal memory (4GB), non-rooted and updated 6.0.1 Canvas A1 (AQ4501) works very slow and I tried to root it with many apps but it failed. That's why I don't want to update rooted 4.4.4 canvas A1 (AQ4501).

Comment: have you tried kingo root?

Comment: Yes..I tried Kingo Root with and without PC both and its failed at 13%. For this, I wrote to Kingo Root as well but they wasn't able to fix it.